# How do you use elements from one struct in another struct?

Tags: c, struct, nested, element

For reference, I'm following a mentorship to learn C at my work and the provided code and text is from Zed Shaw's "Learn C the Hard Way", Chapter 17, Extra Credit.

the original code snippet from the working code is:

```
#define MAX_DATA 512
#define MAX_ROWS 100


struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char name[MAX_DATA];
    char email[MAX_DATA];
};

struct Database {
    struct Address rows[MAX_ROWS];
};
```

The extra credit request is

> Change the code to accept parameters for MAX_DATA and MAX_ROWS, store them in the
> Database struct, and write that to the file, thus creating a database that can be arbitrarily
> sized.

I wrote my code as such:

```
//#define MAX_DATA 
//#define MAX_ROWS 

struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    
    struct Database *db;
    char name[db->MAX_DATA];
    char email[db->MAX_DATA];

};

struct Database {
    int MAX_DATA;
    int MAX_ROWS;
    struct Address rows[MAX_ROWS];
};
```

When compiling, I get these errors.

```
    >  error: ‘db’ undeclared here (not in a function)    
       char name[db->MAX_DATA];
                 ^~ 
       error: ‘MAX_ROWS’ undeclared here (not in a function)
         struct Address rows[MAX_ROWS];
                             ^~~~~~~~
```

I'm a bit stumped on this issue/task so hoping someone has some good input. Also please let me know if I am wrong on any terms, as I have not had luck with googling this issue using the terms I have used above.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be using pointers and `malloc`s instead

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are defining structs to use later but you are not creating any instances of them yet. So you cannot refer to `db->MAX_DATA` because `db` does not exist yet, it is just an uninitialized pointer.

Every variable you refer to when you define static arrays must be a constant (the compiler needs to know the final value at compile time, before it is running). When you cannot use constants because you won't know the value until the code is running, you need to use dynamic memory.

```
struct Address {
  char* name;   // declared as pointers because
  char* email;  // they will be dynamically allocated 
};

struct Database {
  int max_data;
  int max_rows;
  struct Address* rows; // declared as another pointer
};

int main() {
  struct Database db;
  // You have to ask for 'max_data' and 'max_rows' normally
  // ...
  // When you know the value of max_rows, you can allocate memory for 'rows':
  db.rows = (struct Address*)malloc(sizeof(struct Address) * db.max_rows);

  for(int i = 0; i < db.max_rows; ++i) {
    // You now have a dynamic array of Address but you still need to allocate memory for 'name' and 'email':
    db.rows[i].name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * db.max_data);
    db.rows[i].email = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * db.max_data);
    // Here you can ask for 'name' and 'email' and store them in db.rows[i] -> TIP: Use fgets()
  }
}
```

PD: Don't forget to free the dynamically allocated memory in the correct order. First you have to free the internal memory (`name` and `email`) and then the external memory (`rows`)